# refresh stream buffer while reading /proc

Tags: c, linux

I'm reading from /proc/pid/task/stat to keep track of cpu usage in a thread.
fopen on /proc/pic/task/stat
fget a string from the stream
sscanf on the string

I am having issues however getting the streams buffer to update.
If I fget 1024 characters if regreshes but if I fget 128 characters then it never updates and I always get the same stats.
I rewind the stream before the read and have tried fsync.

I do this very frequently so I'd rather not reopen to file each time.
What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every program benefits from the use of buffered I/O.

In your case, I think I would just use `read(2)`<sup>1</sup>. This way, you:

- eliminate all stale buffer<sup>2</sup> issues
- probably run faster via the elimination of double buffering
- probably use less memory
- definitely simplify the implementation

For a case like you describe, the efficiency gain may not matter on today's remarkably powerful CPUs. But I will point out that programs like `cp(2)` and other heavy-duty data movers don't use buffered I/O packages.

---

<sup>1. That is, `open(2)`, `read(2)`, `lseek(2)`, and `close(2)`.

2. And perhaps to intercept an argument, on questions related to this one someone usually offers a "helpful" suggestion along the lines of `fflush(stdin)`, and then another someone comes along to accurately point out that `fflush()` is defined by C99 on output streams only, and that it's usually unwise to depend on implementation-specific behavior.</sup>

Comment: I was going to try switching from fopen to open tomorrow.  Hopefully that will work better.